# Car will crank but won't start

Tags: toyota, cranks-wont-run, avalon

I was driving my 2003 Toyota Avalon home yesterday. While driving, I pushed the brake down and the car completely stalled.

I shut it off and tried to start it up again but it won't start. The car cranks but won't start. I checked all the fuses and they are all good. All the lights in the car work fine. I also tried starter spray in the air intake and it still won't start so its not the fuel pump.

I'm a little lost. Also the brakes are REALLY hard to depress. I'm gonna tow it to a mechanic if I can't figure it out but I would like to not have to pay for anything crazy. I'm really good with mechanical repairs. But I'm not knowledgeable enough to diagnose problems. HELP!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Technically What you mean to say is - My car engine turns over but  it does not start.  *Cranking and turning over are the same thing*. The starter is turning the crank and pistons but the engine is not starting.

Comment: I've edited the title and body to improve clarity, and divided the question into paragraphs for readability. I've tried to maintain the same facts that you describe. If you disagree with my edits, you can use the "edit" button below the question text and revert to the text which you originally wrote.

Comment: First thing to check is the immobilizer system. On Toyota's of this year the cars will crank over  but not run when activated. To see if it is, locate your flashing security light. generally on the instrument cluster or in the clock area. Then insert your key and turn the switch to the "ON" position (do not try and crank). Flashing means its activated. Off means its good. That said, this would not make your car cut off, It would only prevent it from restarting so you would still have a bigger issue to find. My guess if it is active, then the engine control unit is faulty. Very common on these

Comment: "Also the brakes are REALLY hard to depress."  If the engine's not running the brake pedal will be hard to depress.  This is true of any power-assisted brake system.